# Update data using RetrieveUpdateAPIView - Getting validated data from a serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to update certain properties of a user (say first_name and last_name)
my json object through a PUT request would look like this

```
   {
"user" :    {   
             "first_name": "Jack",   
             "last_name": "shnider",
             "password":"admin123" 
             "email" : "foo@google.com"
             },

"employee_zip" : 12345
}
```

This is what my view looks like (I would like to update the existing fields to these new fields).

These are the serializer

```
  class Serializer_UpdateUser(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','password')

class Serializer_UpdateEmployer(ModelSerializer):
    user = Serializer_UpdateUser()
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployer
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employer_zip',
        ]
```

This is the view :

```
class UpdateProfile_RetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = modelEmployer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializer_UpdateEmployer
    lookup_field = 'user__email'
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object() #------>I have the object that I would like to update
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) #--->Success
```

Now I would like to get a validated fields (The json only contains the fields that have been updated). I know if I do something like this

```
serializer.save
```

I would get back a modelEmployer but instead I get back this error

```
AssertionError at /api/employer/update_profile/employerA@gmail.com/ The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `Employer.api.serializers.Serializer_ListEmployer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields. Request Method:
```

I have two questions

1-Why is save failing ?

2-How can I get the validated data from the above serializer ?

Comment: Please include the serializer in the question.

Comment: Ill update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The save is failing because `django-rest-framework` doesn't deal with nested serializers by default.

**from the [django-rest-framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):**

> By default nested serializers are
>   read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested
>   serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update()
>   methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships
>   should be saved.

You have to override the `update` method in the serializer to allow that behavior:

```
class Serializer_UpdateEmployer(ModelSerializer):
    user = Serializer_UpdateUser()
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployer
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employer_zip',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user', {})
        user_serializer = Serializer_UpdateUser(instance.user, data=user_data)
        user_serializer.save()
        return instance
```

---

Another solution is to use [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested). It automatically makes your nested serializers updatable.

```
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class Serializer_UpdateEmployer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    user = Serializer_UpdateUser()
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployer
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employer_zip',
        ]
```

Comment: any idea how i can get validate data back from the serializer

Comment: in your views use `serializer.data` to get the validated data back. @MistyD

Answer (score 1):

I think [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) can help you to update nested data.

In you case:

```
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation

  class Serializer_UpdateUser(ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        super(Serializer_UpdateUser, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()
        return instance

    def validate_password(self, value):
        password_validation.validate_password(value)
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','password')

class Serializer_UpdateEmployer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    user = Serializer_UpdateUser()
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployer
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employer_zip',
        ]
```

Note you need special handling `password` field.